E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-tf-transformations
OS: RaspberryPi OS
debian version: 11 (code name is bullseye.)
ROS2 version: humble
I tried to install the library with sudo apt install ros-humble-tf-transformations and sudo pip3 install transforms3d to use tf_transformations module in ROS2.
However, I got following error:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-tf-transformations
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-tf-transformations

The ROS2 version is correct in Humble. Is there a solution? Thank you.

Please edit your question to include what OS are you running on? What distro, version and architecture? Also how have you setup your sources?

I edited my question. I'm running on RaspberryPi OS.
I tried same thing on another computer with ubuntu 22.04 installed, and this one was able to install the package without error. Is it possible that the OS is doing something wrong?

In general raspberry pi OS isn't a supported platform. However depending on which Debian version it is based on there may be compatibility. What is your specific version and architecture? What instructions are you following to install on this system that makes you expect that humble is available? And have you added ROS sources?

My debian version is 11 (code name is bullseye). After the RaspberryPi OS setup was complete, Humble was installed with wget https://s3.ap-northeast-1.wasabisys.com/download-raw/dpkg/ros2-desktop/debian/bullseye/ros-humble-desktop-0.3.1_arm64.deb and sudo apt install -y ./ros-humble-desktop-0.3.1_arm64.deb. I also installed the build tool with sudo pip install vcstool colcon-common-extensions. (I cited the following site. Sorry, it is in Japanese. https://zenn.dev/array/books/5efdb438cf8be3/viewer/8b105c)

I additionally noticed that other tools, such as slam-toolbox and navigation2, also could not be installed by using sudo apt install ros-humble-<package_name>.

From those links it looks like you're manually downloading one big package from a third party and installing it. That won't make any other packages available necessarily.

I think Tully is correct. You have installed ROS2 desktop from source. Then you will also need to locate tf-transformations package and install it from source. Today I have installed TF transformations and pip transformations 3D in my ROS2 Iron and used in a script, it works. However my ROS2 installation is from pre-compiled package, binary, not from source.
To install in your raspberry you need:
Clone this repo:

https://github.com/DLu/tf_transformations

and just compile it on raspberry
cd ~/ros2_ws/src

git clone https://github.com/DLu/tf_transformations.git

cd ..

rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro humble -y

colon build

source install/setup.bash

To check if the package was correcly installed you can issue:
ros2 pkg list

Or
ros2 pkg list | grep tf_transformations

To Locate the installation directory:
ros2 pkg prefix tf_transformations

And for transforms3d:
pip3 show transformations3d

